# How to setup an iPad rig to use the iPad surface as a mouse or trackpad when connected to an external monitor?

Tags: ipad, trackpad

Imagine if you will, that you want to use your ipad as a desktop computer.

You have connected it to an external screen and have an external keyboard. That is working for you.

But now you now want to use the iPad itself as a giant trackpad. The ipad screen can be completely blank or black and a cursor is displayed on the connected monitor.

I know it sounds cRaZy but is this impossible?

I know there are similar posts where you can use an ipad with a Mac computer but this question is slightly different. There is no computer. Please double check before marking as duplicate. Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: You mean how it works out of the box on iOS 13 with the Digital AV adapter to connect a screen and a bluetooth mouse/keyboard attached for input?  Other than not being blank, this is what it does today.

Comment: @Allan that sounds exactly what I want but I do not have mouse attached. So I want to use the screen as a trackpad to move a mouse cursor around. This looks like the Digital AV adapter, https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207806 but it doesn't solve my problem (without a mouse or trackpad).